# Is it possible to have a nested list that only has text for the bottom level list elements?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I know it is possible to have a nested list that looks like this:

```
1. text
    a. text
    b. text
2. text
    a. text
    b. text
```

But is it possible to have one that looks like this?

```
1. a. text
   b. text
2. a. text
   b. text
```

I don't want to have any text for the higher-level bullets, and I don't want the bullets `1.` and `2.` to take up a whole line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show what you tried but essentially you ask for the default layout

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item text
  \item text
  \end{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item text
  \item text
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```